# Third derivative at point $x=0$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere with $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ real numbers and assume that $f'(0)=2$, what is the value of $f'''(0)$?

I tried to solve it too many times, I put $y=0$ , then $f(0)=1$, I need hints..

Comment: As suggested by lmsavk - don't think about calculus for now but just try to find what sort of functions it is true that `f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)`.  Once you found one such function then you can find f'''(0) for that function, which is progress. (You'd then have to prove that there are no other solutions).

Comment: I disagree with @Matt, in that it is easier to think about calculus and not worry about proving a formula for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: find a solution as a functional equation to $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$. What function is true for this equation?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others have said, think about some exponent rules, and derivatives of exponents.

An equation in which $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$, as far as I can tell, would be an exponential equation. Take for instance, $f(x) = e^x$. Because $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$, this equation satisfies the requirement that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.

However, we are further told that $f'(0)=2$. In order to also satisfy this requirement, we must think about the derivative of $e^{ax}$, which is $ae^{ax}$. $e^{0a}$ is 1, so our first derivative will be equal to the coefficient in front of x. In this case, that coefficient must be 2.

At last, we have an equation: $f(x)=e^{2x}$. Deriving this 3 times, we get $f'''(x)=8e^{2x}$, and finally, $f'''(0)=8$.

*As an aside note, this is my first post here so if I have broken any rules, or you need any further clarification, just let me know.*

Comment: Like which ones?

Comment: a^(x+y) = a^x * a^y

Comment: This is now a good answer, but there's a gap in establishing that the function must be exponential.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the derivative with respect to $x$, then $y$, then evaluate at $x=y = 0$. This will tell you $f''(0)$

Then you can take the derivative with respect to $x$ again, and evaluate at $x=y=0$ again.  This will tell you $f'''(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\implies f'(x)f(y)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x+y)=f'(x+y)=\frac{d}{dy}f(x+y)=f(x)f'(y)$
Implies $f'(x)f(0)=f(x)f'(0)$ and $f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)$.
So $f'(x)=2f(x)$ why $f(x)=e^{2x}$ so $f'''(0)=8$.

Answer (score 0):

my try was using the definition of derivative using limit..

By putting $y=0$, I get $f(0)=1$, by limit I get something like $f'(x)=f(x)f'(0)$ .

but I did not notice it something like $e^x$.

I'll be careful next time.

thank you